# How do I plot the map of east africa (kenya, uganda and tanzania) in R with library(maps) and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am trying to map the east african continent specific to my research paper. In particular tanzania, kenya and uganda using the packages `maps` and `ggplot` in R? I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where exactly are you getting stuck? It's easier to help if you show what you've tried so far.

Comment: map('world', c('kenya', 'tanzania', 'uganda'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
require(maps)

map(database = "world", regions =  c('kenya', 'tanzania', 'uganda'))
```

Result:

[image]

In addition, try to look [here](https://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html) and [here](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly, figured it out as well after like half an hour haha

Comment: Glad I could help, and try to look at the links I added. They have step-by-step instructions :)